# Button Background Animation: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Background'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am trying to add animation on mouse hover to my control template set up for buttons in my wpf application

Here is my code:

```
<Style x:Key="scanButtonActive" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" BorderBrush="#575757" BorderThickness="0,6,0,0" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ScanButton">

                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation From="#6d6e6e" To="#b2b2b2" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="ScanButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation From="#b2b2b2" To="#6d6e6e" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="ScanButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>           
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7, 3, 7, 3" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 10" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#6d6e6e" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>               
</Style>
```

However I get the following error when hovering over a button:

Cannot resolve all property references in the property path `Background`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong.

First `ContentPresenter` does not have a `Background` property. You might set the `Background` of the `Border` control instead.

Second, `Background` is of type `Brush`, but a `ColorAnmation` animates a `Color`, so you should change the property path to `Background.Color`.

Third (for completeness), you should explicitly assign a `SolidColorBrush` to the `Background` property, which is guaranteed to be modifiable.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border" ...>
                    ...
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    To="#b2b2b2" Duration="0:0:1"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="border" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    To="#6d6e6e" Duration="0:0:1"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ...
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#6d6e6e"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Please note also that you do not have to set the animation's `From` values explicitly.

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the code and the information allowing me not to make this error again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code instead:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation From="#6d6e6e" To="#b2b2b2" Duration="0:0:1" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ScanButton" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Control.Background"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation From="#b2b2b2" To="#6d6e6e" Duration="0:0:1" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ScanButton" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Control.Background"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```